# How are the various widgets connected with each other in Foundry Workshop?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I just want to understand how the data flow occurs between the various widgets behind the scenes. For instance, if you have checkbox, bar chart, some graphs, and if i want the charts to update based on the state of the checkbox, how does that work behind the scenes? Is it an event-driven architecture?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.